# Getting waf to output solution to another directory

Tags: python, waf

I recently wrote this simple waf build script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')
    opt.load('msvs')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')

def build(bld):
    print('build')
```

but the problem is that the outputed solution file is at the root of the project (where wscript is);

[image: Project Structure after running waf]

Would there be a way to generate the ide specific files into another directory (for instance, ide/msvs) ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `out="my/out/dir"` on top of your waf script? This should solve your problem. See https://waf.io/book/#_build_related_commands

Comment: Thanks; i'll try it when i'll have time. For now, I've switched to cmake out of frustration. Do you have any experience with waf for large projects ?

Comment: I am working in one bigger project with `waf`. The toolchain has grown rapidly, at this time it is pretty mighty but also relatively complex. I don’t know if it would be better if I was using some sort of ` make`. I will make my comment an answer, as it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the solution by using

```
out = os.path.join('my', 'out', 'dir')
```

which is relative to the `top_dir` (https://waf.io/apidocs/Context.html?highlight=top_dir#waflib.Context.top_dir).

So in your case:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import os

out = os.path.join('my', 'out', 'dir')

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')
    opt.load('msvs')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')

def build(bld):
    print('build')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I've just tested the code; the solution file (.sln) is still being generated where wscript is ...

Comment: `out` is relative to the `top_dir`. You can put the `out` directory, the directory where the output of the build process is put to, also outside of the `top_dir`, just set the `out` dir to `out = os.path.join('..', 'my', 'out', 'dir', 'outside', 'of', 'top_dir')`

Comment: That's what I did; it works for the generated executables (it's going to the bin folder where i specified), but the solution file for some reason does not want to go there...